# Laravel 5 Database Querying help wanted

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, laravel-5

I`m new to the laravel 5 .but for my project i have to do it using this framework.so that i need to get this done either.
[image]

Here is my index page.what i need is when i click green color See here button.i need to see all the details related to that trainee id.see the database attributes as follows.

[image]

Um try to achieve it but i don`t know how to get that data.can anyone help me to complete this controller and the related view for that.

```
 public function user_details()
{
    $items = registerdetails::all();
     return view('registeredusers.seedetails', compact('items'));
}
```

So relevent view need to link into button as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that button you need to give link something like this,

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('trainee/'.$traninee->id.'/details') }}">Details</a>
```

You need to define a route for that view something like below,

```
Route::get('{traninee_id}/details', array('as' => 'traineedetails', 'uses' => 'TraineeController@traineedetails'));
```

In your Trainee controller you need an action named 'traineedetails'

Then use something like this,

```
function traineedetails($traninee_id){
     $trainee_details= Trainee::where('id','=',$traninee_id)->get()->first();
      return view('traineedetails', compact('trainee_details'));
}
```

Hope you already have Trainee models

Comment: Thank you sir,can you please show me how to call trainee_details in a view?it will be very appropriated

Comment: you can use like this {{ $traineedetails->full_name}}

Comment: Sir,it tried out your code but it give this error.how can i fix it?Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value

Answer (score 1):

You can search the data by `id` using Eloquent. in laravel as

```
public function user_details($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
}
```

Assuming you have a `User` model defined and that is using this table of your database.

Comment: Sir,thank you for the suggestions.so that if i filter that how can i calle it in the view?

Comment: Post your `web.php` and your view file for more elaborate answer.